# Can a batch file check if temp in pc is to hot?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to test the temp of a pc via a batch file, is that possable?  Any creative ways you can think of?

Comment: Why don't people [google](http://www.google.co.in/search?rls=en&q=batch+file+to+check+pc+temperature&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) it at first?

Comment: first link is here :D  second link has no answer,  3rd link is from 2011...and 4th or last one , is block for me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can.

you might use **wmi** to get the temperature in the various thermal zones in your system.

```
WMIC /namespace:\\root\WMI path MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature Get CurrentTemperature,InstanceName
```

the temperature is returned in decikelvins.

depending on your requirements you might want to average or take the maximum temp reading and check against a limit...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set maxtemp=0
FOR /F "skip=1" %%A IN ('WMIC /namespace:\\root\WMI path MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature Get CurrentTemperature') DO (
  if %%A gtr !maxtemp! set maxtemp=%%A
)
if !maxtemp! gtr 3500 echo its too darn hot in here
```

or depending on your requirements you might want to average the temperatures, instead.

Comment: wmic is not included in xp.

Comment: it is included in XP professional, and it's a free download from microsoft, indeed.